# bipolar to unipolar voltage converter

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a +3.5V/-3.5V AC signal (audio frequency range) that I need to convert to 0V/5V range so that I can use it as input for an ADC.

I was trying to use a non-inverting summing opamp, but I can't figure how to calculate the resistors.

I know that I need a gain of 7.14 (5V/7V) + 2.5V offset, but I don't understand how to determine the resistors for the non-inverting topology (assuming 5V as voltage reference for the offset).

can anyone help me understand how to calculate that? thank you

Comment: If you can allow for the required charging time, why not allow a capacitor to charge up with the offsetting difference? What kind of load can your source accept?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it goes with a simple voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBZpR0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just in case you don't have a 10.5VDC supply, you can cap couple it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f99smr.png)</sup>

The actual values would depend on the lowest frequency you need to measure.

Comment: My understanding is that the signal is -3.5V to +3.5V therefore 7Vpp, so this wont work and the signal will still go below 0V (Also above VDD)

Comment: You can add a series resistor after the cap to reduce the amplitude if you wish.